# posted code sample is not properly displayed

Tags: bug, questions, code

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

All the time I post a code sampe on SO, the display is not as desired. Here some examples with simple text from a notepad document:

1) no whitespaces, beginning of the lines

bla
bla

it looks like

```
bla
```

bla

2) text has one tab (alternatively: 4 spaces) in each line before the text

bla
    bla

The display is

```
    bla
bla
```

I nearly every time have to do a lot of rearranging of the code to make it look nicely.

Comment: Indent code by four spaces. No tabs, tabs are evil.

Comment: please see my edit

Comment: You still have tabs in that. I checked.

Comment: Is this a rant, or are you actually asking a question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To format code properly, have a blank line before and after each code block and *begin each line of code with four spaces*. Spaces, ASCII 32, 0x20. No fancy stuff like tabs or non-breaking spaces.

The easiest way to get that is to paste the code, select it and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd> or click on the `{}` icon above the text area.

If you have tabs in the code itself, that may or may not cause funny-looking indentation, but it is absolutely essential that the code lines begin with **four spaces**.